# geborgen vs sicher

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, swiss-standard-german

To say that the place is safe and secure which verb will be used : geborgen or sicher?
I have generally seen sicher adjectiv while reading.
I tried using geborgen adjective as in this sentence:
It's a place, wherein one feels safe.

Es ist ein Ort, an dem man sich geborgen fuehlen.

To verify, I used translator.
Translator:
Es ist ein Ort, an dem man sich sicher fühlen kann.

Comment: Neither "geborgen" nor "sicher" is a verb.

Comment: @idmean thank you I have made the changes sorry for my absent mind

Answer (score 3):

As idmean already mentioned in the comments to your question, both "sicher" and geborgen" aren't verbs, but adjectives.

Regarding the difference between the two, "sicher" has a more objective vibe to it, while "geborgen" is more about the subjective feeling. "Geborgen" is a form of the verb "bergen", which means something like "to rescue", "to salvage", "to remove from a dangerous place", "to bring to safety".

So to say that somebody is "geborgen" has the connotation that the person has been vulnerable to danger of some kind, and now is saved, is sheltered, is secured. As an adjective, "geborgen" is mostly used in expressions like "sich geborgen fühlen". This puts further emphasis on the subjective feeling.

To illustrate, think about a small child getting startled and scared by something. The child starts to cry, feels like it's in danger somehow. But then mommy comes and takes the child into her arms. Now, the child feels save again, feels protected, feels sheltered from any harm - it "fühlt sich geborgen" from the perceived danger.

If you combine "sicher" with "sich fühlen" as well, the difference becomes smaller, because then "sicher" is about the subjective feeling of security as well.